# ENOTDIR: not a directory node_modules/.staging/@types/node-16824c86/package.json

Tags: docker, node-modules, package.json, staging

It error When I run docker exec -t [image] npm run production.

npm WARN ws@8.2.3 requires a peer of utf-8-validate@^5.0.2 but none was installed.

npm ERR! Linux 4.10.0-35-generic

npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "--save"

npm ERR! node v6.9.5

npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10

npm ERR! path /var/www/localhost/htdocs/node_modules/.staging/@types/node-16824c86/package.json

npm ERR! code ENOTDIR

npm ERR! errno -20

npm ERR! syscall open

npm ERR! ENOTDIR: not a directory, open '/var/www/localhost/htdocs/node_modules/.staging/@types/node-16824c86/package.json'

Would appreciate any ideas, thanks so much!

Comment: Could you post your package.json?