# Bitbucket Pipeline fails at Step: NPM Install

Tags: angularjs, npm, bitbucket-pipelines

Angular version 1.4

Bitbucket pipeline failed at NPM Install. here are the logs

```
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@~2.3.2
(node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.3.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules/karma/node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN ws@8.2.3 requires a peer of bufferutil@^4.0.1 but none was installed.
npm WARN ws@8.2.3 requires a peer of utf-8-validate@^5.0.2 but none was installed.
npm WARN dashboardApp@0.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN dashboardApp@0.0.0 No license field.
npm ERR! Linux 5.13.0-1031-aws
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v6.11.4
npm ERR! npm v3.10.10
npm ERR! path /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/node_modules/.staging/@types/node-43f1e04b/package.json
npm ERR! code ENOTDIR
npm ERR! errno -20
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! ENOTDIR: not a directory, open '/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/node_modules/.staging/@types/node-43f1e04b/package.json'
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR! https://github.com/npm/npm/issues
npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR! /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/npm-debug.log
```

Comment: Duplicate for https://stackoverflow.com/q/72729079/11715259 isn't it?

Comment: Also question is pretty poor. What versions of node and npm are you using? Can you reproduce the issue in your workstation? Not even an actual question phrased as such just... "here are the logs"... Ok, bye. A 1 minute search of the error message leads to a bunch of threads of people trying to narrow down the rotten apple in their dependency tree that is causing the error.  What have you tried so far? Sorry but your real problem is that you are not able to extract the meaningful information from those logs.

Comment: NPM version : 3.10.10 & nvm version 0.38.0

Comment: Not Duplicate for stackoverflow.com/q/72729079/11715259. This is related to bitbucket pipeline. @N1ngu

Comment: using node v6.11.4 (npm v3.10.10)

Comment: There might be just an issue with bitbucket itself. Have experienced issues with them several times. Sometimes it just starts crashing, and the next day (or so) it starts working again without any changes. If you can't narrow it down to your code, try contacting their support. Good Luck

Comment: @N1ngu, if the question is poor then the answer might come easy to you. I dont see any answer in the original thread or in this thread. Why not add the answer on either thread first and then mark either one as duplicate later. It appears in Google due to SEO but because of people like you, there isnt any answer.